# Uninstalled gtk and ubuntu freezes in login

Tags: xubuntu, uninstall, screen, login-screen, gtk

Summary:
Unintentionally removed gtk from my xubuntu and now it is stuck at xubuntu loading screen.

Details:
I wanted to uninstall libjson-glib-1.0 but it uninstalled gtk as well which i didnt think would do anything and I closed the terminal and saw that many of my applications suddenly disappeared in the menu and I couldnt start the terminal again as there was a error shown in the window. So I restarted my PC thinking it would be fixed by itself but now I am stuck with the xubuntu loading screen. After a while or some random key press on my keyboard I saw a screen with log of data looping and failing over and over again non stop like this [Photo](https://photos.app.goo.gl/sP8xwGXqa9zLJmHu7)

Here is a [video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/1ouNdEuCTmD8eX8y6) of how the logs are repeating itself over and over.

So what is the solution to revert it to normal or do I have to reinstall ubuntu in my system again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have actually found the solution to the problem.
First it is needed to ender the recovery mode. For which shift has to be pressed during boot and a menu will appear with the recovery mode option. Select that and then enter the terminal by the root option. 
Then to revert the system applications back to how it was, I used the command - 
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop^`
Thats all it needed. It Automatically then installed the required packages and my pc was back to normal.
Hope anyone with the same problem will be helped.